# edit source code for leaftlet labelFormat to edit breaks/tick marks

Tags: r, colors, formatting, leaflet, legend

I'm trying to edit a `leaflet` legend. Does anyone know how to edit the number of `breaks` and where to place `tick-marks` when using a predefined palette from `colorNumeric` (not `colorQuantile`, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/211)) in  `labelFormat`? This is the legend I get (code below) is:

[image]

As you can see, it is a highly skewed legend and would make more sense if the breaks were at `c(1, 3, 6, 9)` or something similar that could easily be edited including limits.

You can include `bins` but these according to the [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.3/topics/addLegend) file will be equally spaced:

[image]

From this [link](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/211) it seems you can do it with `colorQuantile` but thats not what I want here. I think I may need to go through the source code as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234576/r-leaflet-use-date-or-character-legend-labels-with-colornumeric-palette) but I can't see where I could edit `breaks` or tick-marks.

Reproducible code following my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321495/merging-palettes-with-colorramppalette-and-plotting-with-leaflet/) :

```
#following my other question:
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321495/merging-palettes-with-colorramppalette-and-plotting-with-leaflet/
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(var = rnorm(100)^2)
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(var) %>% 
  mutate(ranking = 1:n()) 
threshold <- sum(df$var < 1)   
 # number of values below threshold 
threshold #= 67

### Create an asymmetric color range
## Make vector of colors for values smaller than 1 
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#006837", "#1A9850"), space = "Lab")(threshold)    

## Make vector of colors for values larger than 1
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#FDAE61", "#A50026"), space = "Lab")(length(df$var) - threshold)

## Combine the two color palettes
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)

# Create a palette for a legend with ranking again. But this time with
# colorNumeric()

mypal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = rampcols, domain = df$ranking)

leaflet() %>% 
  addLegend(pal = mypal2, values = df$ranking,
            #bins = 10,
            labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) df$var[x]))
```

Would anyone have any suggestions? thanks