# How to change legend text formatting in Leaflet in R?

Tags: r, shiny, formatting, leaflet, legend

I've created a leaflet map and I'm trying to figure out how I can change the formatting of the legend labels. I currently have a gradient color palette to represent the data, with a set of discrete labels. Basically, the current output has the numbers aligned above the tick marks, and I would like them to be centered with the tick mark and justified left. See this image for reference.

[image]

```
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "YlOrRd",
  domain = dat$distance)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%

  addCircleMarkers(data = dat, #eastbound colored circles
                   radius = dat$total_ridership, 
                   stroke = TRUE, 
                   color = ~pal(distance), fillOpacity = 0.8)  


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map") 
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$map = renderLeaflet ({
    m %>%      
        addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = dat$distance, bins = c(0,200,400,600),
            title = "Distance (ft) to <br> nearest bus stop",
            opacity = .8)
   }) 
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I'm quite new to both leaflet and shiny, and I'm going through tutorials to learn how to use shiny as well so I'm gaining a basic understanding of how shiny works, but I'm still confused on how to edit some of the more specific aspects of the leaflet output, especially with the legend. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446283/creating-legend-with-circles-leaflet-r/37482936?noredirect=1#comment103326564_37482936) post to make a custom legend based on circle sizes, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234576/r-leaflet-use-date-or-character-legend-labels-with-colornumeric-palette) on changing the format of time labels, but I'm not sure how to apply this information in my case to edit the legend label formatting -- e.g. changing the position of the text, alignment, etc.

Comment: I had this same problem. I searched the web for hours and dug into the css and html using Chrome's development tools but couldn't find the right css selector.